# Symfony2 Netbeans 8.0.2 Twig files hinting, whispering

Tags: symfony, twig, netbeans-8

I am a newbie so please don't kill me for a silly question.
My problem is when I write in Netbeans a simple function in Controller which is passing a variable, array or something to Twig file, the Twig file is not giving me any hint of variables that I can pick up there.

For example: I pass a variable $helloWorld then in Twig file I start to write "{{" for picking up the variable and I am expecting from Netbeans that he hints me the variable $helloWorld after pressing CTRL+Spacebar.

I know that in this 8.0.2 version of Netbeans all of the plugins are already there so I don't know where to look at anymore. If you have any idea, please tell me. I thank you in advance for your answers :)

Comment: You are expecting Netbeans to be too intelligent. It is very difficult to connect a template with a controller and to know which variables are being passed. I don´t think this is or will be available

Comment: Yes I understand, I asked for that because in Nette framework it is possible. I am trying Symfony now so I was just wondering if it is possible here too, but thx for your answer ;-)

Comment: PHPStorm has that feature if the symfony2 Plugin is installed. Not always reliable but most of the time it works pretty well. There is also a symfony plugin for Netbeans which already is downloaded and active I suppose?

Comment: Yes that plugin is part of Netbeans in this version. Thx for proposal of PHPStorm, I think that Eclipse can do that feature also, but we use Netbeans and probably wont change it.. but thx